# Automatically interacting with winforms application programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a winforms application up and working. However, I am now writing a script to run this application and the goal is to have it do an automated task within the application.

For example, I have a few dropdown list combo boxes and a button I want to select and click in my test.

The main confusion I have is how to go about this/where to put this code. Since most of the code is based on events like `_onIndexChanged()` or `_click()` where it is dependent on the user interacting with the application, I don't know where to write the code as to programmatically select these dropdowns and click my button.

I originally wanted to have it in the main method like so:

```
ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
Application.Run(new Form1());
// select from dropdown
// select from dropdown
// click button
Application.Exit();
```

I don't think I can put it in the main() method as when I run `Application.run(new Form 1())` it will not execute further commands after it unless the application has closed. My next thought was to do this in the constructor of Form1 but I don't think that is quite right either.

Is there somewhere I can put this code in a spot that will be guaranteed to run that isn't in the main method or in the constructor?

What I'm trying to do isn't to do unit tests on my application but I'm more trying to automate a process within my application. This part isn't part of my question but to give a more clear picture of how I'm doing this, I'm writing a build graph script in XML and when I run this script through CLI, it should run this application and it will automate a series of instructions within the application to execute.

I also want to keep this application a standalone tool itself so users can manually interact with this application (selecting from dropdowns or clicking buttons), but there is just a specific process I want to automate when it is run by a script.

Comment: Why use a UI at all? Something like this could be converted to a Windows Service and scheduled to run at certain times

Comment: Please clarify the purpose of the script you're writing. Is it to exercise and test your UI? When you say _I want to select and click in my test_ is it that you want to do these things programmatically by way of testing?

Comment: This was originally going to be a standalone C# app that users can interact with and use. However, now we also want to be able to automate one of the features in this application.

Sorry for the vagueness, this isn't as much as for testing as more of to automate a process in the application